# Robospice - SpiceList UI 1.4.4 usage samples?

Tags: robospice

I'm using Robospice with SpringForAndroid frameworks and I have to implement a twitter-like wall with tweets containing either a profile image and a tweet image (eg. a photo) and this should be supported through SpiceList UI Robospice's extension. The problem is that the [sample about this extension](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-ui-spicelist/src/com/octo/android/robospice/sample/ui/spicelist)  refers to an older version of the framework, and the current implementation looks different. Does anyone know the usage of SpiceList UI in 1.4.4 version of Robospice?

Especially I want to know how to implement the [`SpiceArrayAdapter`](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/blob/release/extensions/robospice-ui-spicelist-parent/robospice-ui-spicelist/src/main/java/com/octo/android/robospice/spicelist/SpiceArrayAdapter.java) to support objects with more than one image to be downloaded. The problem is that the `SpiceArrayAdapter`'s `createRequest()` method supports only one BitmapRequest to be returned. What if a single object contains two image to be downloaded?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [robospice-sample-ui-spicelist](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-ui-spicelist) was updated to latest version and the new APIs now support more than one image per cell view!